# Verification algorithm for minimum vertex cover?

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex, np-complete

We know that the minimum vertex cover is NP complete, which means that it is in the set of problems that can be verified in polynomial time.

As I understand it, the verification process would require the following:

1. Verify that the solution is a vertex cover at all
2. Verify that the solution is the smallest possible subset of the source graph that satisfies condition #1

I'm finding it hard to establish that step #2 can be done in polynomial time.  Can anyone explain how it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum vertex cover is NP-hard. It is only NP-complete if it is [restated as a decision problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover_problem#Computational_problem) which can be verified in polynomial time.

> The minimum vertex cover problem is the optimization problem of finding a smallest vertex cover in a given graph.
>
> - INSTANCE: Graph *G*
> - OUTPUT: Smallest number *k* such that *G* has a vertex cover of size *k*.
>
> If the problem is stated as a [decision problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem), it is called the vertex cover problem:
>
> - INSTANCE: Graph *G* and positive integer *k*.
> - QUESTION: Does *G* have a vertex cover of size at most *k*?

Restating a problem as a decision problem is a common way to make problems NP-complete. Basically you turn an open-ended problem of the form "find the smallest solution *k*" into a yes/no question, "for a given *k*, does a solution exist?"

For example, for the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem), verifying that a proposed solution the *shortest* path between all cities is NP-hard. But if the problem is restated as only having to find a solution shorter than *k* total distance for some *k*, then verifying a solution is easy. You just find the length of the proposed solution and check that it's less than *k*.

The decision problem formulation can be easily used to solve the general formulation. To find the shortest path all you have to do is ratchet down the value of *k* until there are no solutions found.

Comment: But if something is easy it doesn't mean it's fast too solve? Np problem takes long time and that's the problem.

Comment: @Phpdna There's a critical distinction between *finding* solutions, which is NP, and *verifying* solutions, which is P. An NP-complete problem is one for which it is possible to verify solutions "easily" (in polynomial time). I don't know how to find a way to hit five cities in 500 miles, but if someone hands me a solution I can very easily check that their route is shorter than 500 miles.

Comment: Still it doesn't say anything about the solution. The thing about finding something (decision) problem is this really that difficult to understand? After all it's not even a true science?